# Array.IndexOf()をByteに変換したかったですが、「stringに変換できません」と表示されました

Tags: c#

御覧の様に、`Int32`である配列の指数を取得し、これをByteに変換してみましたが、どういう訳か「stringに変換する事ができません」と表示されます:

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`Byte someEntityNumber = Byte.Parse(Array.IndexOf(entities, someEntitiy));`を `Int32 someEntityNumber = Array.IndexOf(entities, someEntitiy);`にしますと、エラー表示がなくなります。

`SomeEntity`について情報が必要でしたら、このようなクラスになります：

```
class SomeEntity : INotifyPropertyChanged  {

    public SomeEntity() {

    }

    private Boolean someProperty = false;
    public Boolean SomeProperty { 
        get => someProperty;
        set {
            someProperty = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(someProperty)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.IndexOf()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/eha9t187(v=vs.110).aspx)の戻り値は`int`型です。`int`型から`byte`型への変換は[明示的変換](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions)が必要です。

```
int someEntityNumber = Array.IndexOf(entities, someEntitiy);
// or
byte someEntityNumber = (byte)Array.IndexOf(entities, someEntitiy);
```

なお`Byte.Parse()`は

> 数値の文字列形式を、それと等価の Byte に変換します。

と説明されているように文字列を解析するメソッドです。

Comment: ご回答とご説明、誠に感謝致します！非常に助けてくださいました。